# Coming from d'Alembert's formula, write expressions for $h_1(z)$ and $h_2(z)$ in terms of $f(z)$ for all $z.$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Let $u(x, t)$ be the displacement of a string, at position $x$ and time $t$, which is stretched between two fixed points at $x = 0$ and $x = 1$. Its motion satisfies the wave equation, $$u_{tt} = c^2u_{xx}\qquad x ∈ (0, 1),\: t > 0$$

where $c$ is a real positive constant, and is subject to boundary conditions
$$u(0, t) = u(1, t) = 0 \qquad t > 0$$

The string has an initial displacement $u(x, 0) = f(x), x ∈ (0, 1)$ and is initially at rest.

Starting with the general solution to the wave equation
$$u(x, t) = h_1(x − ct) + h_2(x + ct)$$

for arbitrary functions $h_1(z)$ and $h_2(z)$,

write expressions for $h_1(z)$ and $h_2(z)$ in terms
of $f(z)$ for all $z.$

I asked a different question relating to this example a couple of days Ive become stuck again.

So any help will be appreciated.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2254121/by-using-dalemberts-formula-substitute-pz-and-qz-into-the-general-sol

Comment: near exact duplicate of above question